# trying to edit user profile (/user/4/edit/?destination=admin%2Fuser%2Fuser) results in error

Tags: 6, users

Clicking on the edit link for any user (even admin) listed in `".../admin/user/user"` results in an error page.

"The page isn't redirecting properly"

Link goes something like this `"edit?destination=admin%2Fuser%2Fuser"`

To be honest, I don't have full access to this Drupal install so I cannot turn on/off modules to test freely.

Has anyone encountered this kind of error? Which modules could be most likely to produce this error?

Thanx in advance.

Comment: I found the culprit: Account Profile module, redirect option. I disabled that and problem solved.

Comment: Please post the solution to your question as an answer and mark it as accepted when you can.  It will make it easier for future visitors with the same problem to find a solution

Comment: I wanted too, but I'm too new here yet.
-- 
Last night I couldn't, but I just tried it and worked. :)

Answer (score 2):

I found the culprit: the redirection option of the Account Profile module. I disabled that and the problem has been solved.